# Google Analytics showing different values for "New Users"

Tags: google-analytics

I found Google Analytics showing different values for New User under Acquisition and New User under New VS Returning User in Behavior. May I know why are they different?

Answer (score 3):

New User under Acquisition is a metric and is the number of first-time users to your site, during the selected date range.

New *Visitor* under the under New VS Returning,in Audience > Behavior reports is a dimension.

New Users should = the same number in the Audience overview and also the Acquisition reports and as a new visitor in the New VS Returning.

Keep in mind, total Users for the date range, will not be the sum of New Vs Returning Users as a User can be both New and then Returning
eg -at the time of their first visit during the selected date range they were New, then if they returned during that same date range.. they are then also reported as a Returning Visitor.